# How to add list of foreign keys inside one column sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a Comment model that has a "ownerId" which is the person who created it and the users have the option to like/dislike a comment and to keep track of how already liked/disliked a comment is.  I think that I need a list of foreign keys. There is also the option to make another table with comment id and user id but isn't this worse?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to ask here and sounds like an XY problem.  You should include your code, table schema, and sample data to help describe your situation better.  What is it that you are really trying to achieve?

Comment: *but isn't this worse?* No, storing a list of values in one column is really bad.

Comment: seems like you're describing a many-to-many relationship?  Check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a few stated?

DO NOT try and munge this up by storing multiple values in one column. It seems like a great idea, but you REALLY lose any and all abilities to allow the beautiful thing we have called a relational database.

Bite the bullet - grab that cup of coffee, and do this right.

So, create a new table. That table is a list of voted comments. MUCH better is you can now use sql to:

- Get the current user voted (up or down) - easy to let them change.
- Get the total number of votes (up or down) with sql query
- Easy add and extend the design - say date when up/down voted great statics.

The above list could be longer - but really, just even when you display the comments, you no doubt want to show the CURRENT users choice (or maybe they don't have a choice, but those operations will be ONE record, and you can change the up vote, the down vote and as noted, maybe even save the date of when the user did this.

It is going to be a simple table.  Say like this:

[image]
I mean, just to count the up-votes, just to edit + save?

All this will become plane jane data operations.

You try and stuff into one column all those id? Now you have to parse out, fetch the one id - maybe not found. And then how about a simple query to show up votes and down votes? Again, messy.

If this was a xml, or even a json database (no-sql), then maybe ok.

But, if this is a sql database? Then do this the right way. I love json or even xml types of databases, but in sql land?

Do as they do in Rome, and in this case?

Do as they do in the Country of sql land!

## Edit: the User to up-votes table cascade delete problem

Ok, we have a follow up issue.

Assume we have this setup.

I have Users->comments->upvotes.

So each table is a child of previous.

So, if we delete comments, we cascade delete votes

So, if we delete a user, we cascade delete comments, which in turn will cascade delete votes.

BUT WE ALSO want to cascade delete votes for a given user - even if they never made a comment, they still could have lots of up-votes.

So, lets assume we have the first part - we now have 3 tables like this:

[image]

So each child table (starting left side - users), will cascade delete.

Now, our last issue. We COULD and CAN enforce reverential integrity for when we add a voting record, that user_ID MUST exist.

Now, I would argue that is impossible to mess up, since if a user going to vote, then they MUST exist, right?

So, we can STILL however enforce the above, and for the sake of documentation, we should.

HOWEVER!!! - we can NOT turn on cascade delete. First lets enforce this rule, and we now have this:

[image]
So, we can enforce this rule, but we can NOT set cascade delete here.

Why?

Well, when you delete user, we cascade delete ->comments->votes

But, we ALSO can cascade delete from users->votes.
So, two operations can cascade to the SAME table!!!!

This would ONLY occur in the case that a user made a comment, and ALSO upvoted their own comment. This might not be allowed, but SQL server don't know that.

So, two potential deletes could not only occur to the same table, but in fact EVEN the same record!!!

Unfortantly SQL server does NOT allow the above. (and I think it should!!!).

MS-Access allows this - but it not 100% "ACID" database. And so what if we delete some votes by deleting the user and the cascade comes from comments table, AND THEN the cascade from users->votes fires.

I don't have experience with say Oracle, or MySQL to know if this is allowed, but it is NOT allowed with SQL server. (again: I think it should be). I suspect that since each operation has to be "distinct", and also run as separate threads for performance, we would now have two cascades in operations that could potentially delete the same record.

The only practical solution then?

You have to add a delete trigger to the User delete event. When you delete, you let it cascade, and THEN will have to run a query to delete all votes that belong to the user.

Now you could also do this the other way around. Put a trigger on Comments table to delete votes, and then a cascade delete from users->votes.

I think its better to have tblComments do the delete in votes, and then you run that trigger for users->votes table.

As noted, having the two cascades that eventually resolve to the same table FROM ONE delete commend is not allow, and sql server will spit out a message that reads:

> Unable to create relationship 'FK_tblCommentVotes_Users'.
> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_tblCommentVotes_Users' on table
> 'tblCommentVotes' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify
> ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN
> KEY constraints. Could not create constraint or index.

The critical part from above is this:

***may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.***

so that error message is in a nutshell the exact same issue I outlined in my narrative here - more then one path to a cascade delete exists from a same possible parent table.

Comment: I have added a new table like in your but i can't connect the tblCommentVotes to user table via a foreign key because I get a loop if i use on delete cascade and if i have on delete no action I get a foreign key violation when I'm deleting an user. For now I just removed the foreign key relation on that column but it should be there. Should I update the question with some code + images?

Comment: See my edit and explain of your  problem - you are 100% correct - and I outline the options you have in dealing with this issue.